# Ms Sql построить роллап

Tags: sql-server

Всем привет, нужно построить роллап (таблицу с подсчитанными на основе других данными).
Есть таблица Sale (SaleId, CustomerId)
У каждого сейла может быть несколько категорий, которые можно взять с таблицы SaleCategory (SaleId, CategoryId).
Нужно построить таблицу Rollup с подсчитанными за все даты и категори данными. 
Rollup( CustomerId, CategoryId, NumOfSales)
Роллап долзженвключать данные по каждому измерению, включая все (например все CategoryId).
Примерный результат:

```
Rollup(CustomerId, CategoryId, NumOfSales)
1     1    3
1     2    1
1     3    5
1     ALL  7
2     1    3
2     ALL  3
3     2    1
3     3    5
3     ALL  6
ALL   1    6
ALL   2    2
ALL   3    10
ALL  ALL   16
```

Для этого я делаю
1. Просто сумма сейлов по категориям для кастомеру

```
select customerId, categoryId, count()
from Sale s join Category c on s.SaleId = c.SaleId
group by customerId, categoryId
```

В итоге получаем что-то типа:

```
CustomerId, CategoryId, NumOfSales
1           1           3
1           2           1
1           3           5
2           1           3
3           2           1
3           3           5
```

Теперь нам надо найти сейлы по всем категориям. Вот тут и начинаются проблемы, ткк один сейл одного кастомера может попасть под несколько категорий, и просто сгруппировать дальше и просуммировать не получится. Как тут быть?
Если сделать select `customerID, categoryId, sum(numOfSales) from Rollup group by customerID,  categoryId`, то появятся дубли, если у одного кастомера в одном сейле много категорий.

**UPD**
Fidle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fae50/3
**UPD2**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9a7d0/5

Comment: на ваш вопрос практически не реально ответить не видя исходных данных во всех участвующих таблицах. на sqlfiddle бы сделали небольшой пример ...

Comment: @Mike, добавил фидл, который частично описывает проблему.

Comment: а всё-таки, какая у вас субд используется? а то заголовок ms sql, и метка sql-server, а fiddle у вас для MySql, это несколько дезориентирует

Comment: @i-one, ms-sql. Фидл по умолчанию такой, я и не.обратил внимание. А вот ваш пример мне будет довольно сложно транслировать в мс сиквел. :)

Comment: @sss, а почему? у меня как раз ms-sql, пример для sqlserver 2012, но если заменить `iif` на `case when ... then ... else ... end` то и на sqlserver 2008 сработает

Comment: @sss Кстати, А если вы к своему изначальному запросу, который заполняет таблицу в самый конец, т.е. сразу после `group by customerId, categoryId` добавите фразу `with cube` вы случайно получите не тот результат который вам нужен ?

Comment: Ой, да, невнимательно прочёл, хотя у вас написано, что требуется rollup  фактически всё же требуется cube. `with cube` нормально сработал бы (с `count(distinct ...)` сработает), если бы аддитивность не нарушалась из-за того что одна продажа может быть в нескольких категориях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас есть SaleId, считайте `count(distinct SaleId)` вместо простого количества записей:

```
declare @sale table (saleId int, customerId int, price float)
declare @saleCat table (saleId int, categoryId int)

insert into @sale values
    (1, 1, 100), (2, 1, 200),
    (3, 2, 300), (4, 2, 400),
    (5, 3, 500)

insert into @saleCat values
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1), (2, 2),
    (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
    (4, 2), (4, 3),
    (5, 3)

select
    s.customerId,
    sc.categoryId,
    numSales = count(distinct s.saleId)
from
    @sale s
    join @saleCat sc on sc.saleId = s.saleId
group by
    cube (s.customerId, sc.categoryId)
order by
    grouping(s.customerId), s.customerId,
    grouping(sc.categoryId), sc.categoryId
```

Результат:

```
customerId  categoryId  numSales
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           2
1           2           1
1           NULL        2
2           1           1
2           2           2
2           3           2
2           NULL        2
3           3           1
3           NULL        1
NULL        1           3
NULL        2           3
NULL        3           3
NULL        NULL        5
```

Если нужна сумма, то всё становится несколько сложнее. В этом случае можно сгруппировать отдельно сумму по столбцам, по которым соблюдается аддитивность, и отдельно по тем, где она не соблюдается. Потом соединить два этих результата по соответствующим id и флагам группировки, выбирая сумму из первого или второго результатов:

```
;with custSales (gCust, custId, sales)
as (
    select
        grouping(s.customerId), s.customerId,
        sum(s.price)
    from @sale s
    group by rollup (s.customerId)
),
custCatSales (gCust, custId, gCat, catId, sales)
as (
    select
        grouping(s.customerId), s.customerId,
        grouping(sc.categoryId), sc.categoryId,
        sum(s.price)
    from
        @sale s
        join @saleCat sc on sc.saleId = s.saleId
    group by grouping sets (
        (s.customerId),
        (sc.categoryId),
        (s.customerId, sc.categoryId))
)
select
    customerId = ccs.custId,
    categoryId = ccs.catId,
    sales = iif(ccs.gCat = 0, ccs.sales, cs.sales)
from
    custCatSales ccs
    full join custSales cs on cs.custId = ccs.custId and cs.gCust = ccs.gCust
order by
    isnull(ccs.gCust, 2), ccs.custId,
    ccs.gCat, ccs.catId
```

Результат:

```
customerId  categoryId  sales
----------- ----------- -------
1           1           300
1           2           200
1           NULL        300
2           1           300
2           2           700
2           3           700
2           NULL        700
3           3           500
3           NULL        500
NULL        1           600
NULL        2           900
NULL        3           1200
NULL        NULL        1500
```

Comment: Хм. Да, наверно я недостаточно точно сформулировал вопрос. А если там Sum надо? Заапдейтил фидл.

Comment: @sss, добавил в ответ пример для суммы

Comment: @sss, не разглядел сразу, что у вас фактически не `rollup` а `cube` требуется, поправил ответ, чтобы включалась сумма по категориям